# CodeMagic build fails after adding notification(FCM) service extension

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, codemagic

Im trying to add Firebase Cloud Messaging image service extension to my existing flutter app. I followed this [tutorial](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images) and implemented cloud messaging as shown. Local builds and project works as expected, but CodeMagic pipeline fails at signing step.

> flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=158
> Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
> Building com.xxx.xxxxx for device (ios-release)...
> Running pod install...                                            176.8s (!)
> Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                           666.4s
> Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.

> xcode-project build-ipa --workspace /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner.xcworkspace --scheme Runner --config Release
> Archive Runner.xcworkspace
> Execute "xcodebuild -workspace /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -config Release -archivePath build/ios/xcarchive/Runner_yay86ybq.xcarchive archive COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXXXXXX 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution'"

> error: ImageNotification has conflicting provisioning settings.
> ImageNotification is automatically signed for development, but a
> conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been
> manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "Apple
> Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing
> in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'ImageNotification'
> from project 'Runner')

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? Running into the same issue now